# Create a runit service that doesn't automatically start

Tags: docker, runit

I'm working on a Docker container built on Phusion's [baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) which needs to have a number of services only started on demand. I'd like these services to remain as `runit` services, I'd just like them to not automatically start on boot.

As seen [in their documentation](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#adding_additional_daemons), you can easily add a service by creating a folder in `/etc/service` with the name of your service, ie: `/etc/service/jboss`. Next, you must create and `chmod +x` a file in that service directory called `run` which will execute the startup of your service.

How can I do this and ensure that the service *will not* start on boot? The goal is still to be able to do `sv start jboss`, but to not have it start on boot.

Comment: I don't know if you are not looking for this, but you can add the services as classic sysvinit in `/etc/init.d/<service>` and then use inside the container `service <service> start` whenever you want.

Answer (score 4):

Add your services to `/etc/sv/<SERVICE_NAME>/` and add the `run` executable just like you are doing now. When you are ready to run the service, simply symlink it to `/etc/service` and runit will pick it up and start running it automatically.

Here's a short (non-optimized) Dockerfile that shows a disabled service and an enabled service. The enabled service will start at Docker run. The disabled service will not start until it is symlinked to `/etc/service`, at which time runit will start it within five seconds.

```
FROM phusion/baseimage

RUN mkdir /etc/sv/disabled_service
ADD disabled_service.sh /etc/sv/disabled_service/run
RUN chmod 700 /etc/sv/disabled_service/run

RUN mkdir /etc/sv/enabled_service
ADD enabled_service.sh /etc/sv/enabled_service/run
RUN chmod 700 /etc/sv/enabled_service/run
RUN ln -s /etc/sv/enabled_service /etc/service/enabled_service

CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
```

Comment: The runit documentation doesn't clearly mention it, but I think of this as the standard way to do this. Generally you should not store your runit services directly in /etc/service and should instead symlink them in so you can enable/disable them.

Answer (score 3):

With `phusion/baseimage:0.9.17` (not sure in which version it was introduced) you can bake `RUN touch /etc/service/jboss/down` in your Dockerfile. It prevents the runit from starting it on boot and you're still able to `sv start jboss` later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at *exactly* the same problem (when running Cassandra in a container) and I haven't found a clean answer. Here are the two hacky ways I've come up with.

-Have an early runlevel script that moves a file in and out of `run` depending on whether you want something to start at boot.

-(mis)Use one of the `service` control commands for `runit` to *actually* start your service and use a dummy `run` command to bypass the automatic start.

Both methods are clearly less than ideal, but they've worked for some purposes.

Comment: You might be able to play with the permissions too. ie: `chmod -x run` to prevent start, then `chmod +x run` to enable start.